# How to be exempt from backup withholdings

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, withholding

I have dual citizenship -- US and other -- and I'm living abroad.  What form do I fill out so the paying company will not take out backup withholdings?

Comment: Welcome to [Money.SE].  Please edit your question to provide more information.  Where are you living?  Where are you working?  Where is the paying company located?  Are you an employee or a contractor?  Are you concerned about US taxes or taxes in the country where you are living?

Comment: why are they taking backup withholding to begin with? Have you had some issues with the IRS in the past?

Comment: living and working in france. im a contractor. paying company is in US, i never had trouble with IRS. they just took backup withholding. i would like to know what needs to be done to prevent that from happening.

Comment: living and working in france. im a contractor. paying company is in US, i never had issues with IRS. they just took backup withholding. i would like to know what needs to be done to prevent that from happening. i know there is a w8 or w9 options. so i need to know which one to submit

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to not allow your agent to withhold tax then you need to submit W8 Ben. But in your case its not likely to happen. As you are not allowed. Please read below statement by IRS.

> Do not use Form W-8BEN if You are a U.S. citizen (even if you reside outside the United States) or other U.S. person (including a resident alien individual). Instead, use Form W-9, Request for Taxpayer Identification Number and Certification, to document your status as a U.S. person.

apology to write an answer directly as i am new and have no comments option available.

If you feel if this does not answer your question please comment below. I will try to get back to you.